# MyBatis: How to return the ID of the inserted object under Postgres?

Tags: annotations, ibatis, mybatis

I've got a postgres table where the ID is defined as `bigserial`. How
can I use `@Insert` and get back the id of the inserted entity? I am
expecting the mapper method to either return the id or populate the id
field inside the entity object. Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work me on mysql :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283159/howto-return-ids-on-inserts-with-mybatis-in-mysql-with-annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NVM, i think i found the answer on the other thread, 
http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/How-to-return-the-ID-of-the-inserted-object-under-Postgres-td1926959.html

There's the link for anyone else who lands here.

Answer (score 4):

The mapper will return you the number of records that were actually inserted.
In order to get back the id of the inserted record, you'll need to add a second annotation (that will populate the id) :

`@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="idSomething")`

Note that `keyProperty` is not necessary if the identifiyng property is named "id" in your entity object.