# How to obtain last insert id in Oracle using MyBatis?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm inserting some data into an `Oracle` table and need to retrieve the `id` of the inserted row. Said `id` is being generated by a sequence and then inserted to the table by a trigger.

Now, I know there are several ways to get the id of the inserted row when using `JDBC`, but since I'm using `MyBatis` to execute the `INSERT` command, I can't seem to figure out how to obtain the id after inserting my data. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is a question for MySQL, but hopefully this can steer you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283159/how-to-return-ids-on-inserts-with-mybatis-in-mysql-with-annotations

Comment: @Insert("insert into employees values ('john', 'smith') returning id")

Comment: @MattBusche thanks, reading it right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
class User {
  int userId
  ...
}

<insert id="addUser" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="user_id" keyProperty="userId">
  INSERT INTO user(login, name,...) VALUES(#{login}, #{name},...
</insert>
```

Comment: Thanks. What I don't get yet is how to catch the value returned by the insertion. Is Sqlsession.insert() supposed to return this value instead of the number of inserted rows?

Comment: In my example, the generated key is stored back in User.userId

Answer (score 3):

For me it works like this (mybatis 3)

```
<insert id="create" parameterType="Project" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="project.projectId" keyColumn="PROJECT_ID">
    INSERT INTO PROJECT (TITLE,DESCRIPTION)
    VALUES
    (#{title},#{description})
</insert>
```

No need for selectKey. Just sure to put the correct value in keyProperty..
I have a trigger before insert in oracle to get next id from sequence.

Alternatively this works also:

```
<insert id="createEmpty" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="Panelist">
    BEGIN INSERT INTO PANELIST(PANEL_ID) VALUES (#{panelId})
    RETURNING PANELIST_ID INTO
    #{panelist.panelistId,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER}; END;
</insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the trigger uses id_seq Oracle sequence to get the id. If you execute from MyBatis using the same database session, the SQL

```
select id_seq.currval from dual;
```

You will get the ID used.

Comment: What if another insertion is made to the table just before I go and select the current value from the sequence? Would I get the newly generated id? Or would it give me the right one based on the session?

Comment: Is your session making the insertion into the table or another session?

Is it 

You
Insert table;
Insert table;
id_seq.currval;

Or 
You: insert table
Someone else: insert table
You: is_seq.currval

In the first scenario, id_seq.currval will return the second table id. In the second scenario, id_seq.currval will return your id for table insertion.

Comment: Yes, another session may be doing the insertion.

Comment: If it is another session, then currval is guaranteed by Oracle to return the ID your session last used.

Answer (score 0):

With oracle, better is doing it in two phases. Works well and the price is only one more mapper:

First phase:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"     
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.sample.work.dao.SequencerMapper" >
<select id="selectNextId" resultType="long" >
 select seq_sample.nextval from dual
</select>
</mapper>
```

You obtain the seq, put into your object place holder and

Second Phase:

insert your object