# MyBatis nullPointerException when inserting null

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I'm getting a MyBatis NPE when I try to insert a record with a null primary key and then get the key value value back (an oracle trigger sets the key).

FooMapper interface:

```
...
public void insertFooObject (final Foo foo);
...
```

FooMapper.xml:

```
...
    <insert id="insertFooObject" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="foo_id" keyProperty="fooId">
        insert into foos (foo_id, gcor_id, registration_date)
        values (#{fooId, jdbcType=NUMERIC}, #{gcorId, jdbcType=NUMERIC}, #{registrationDate, jdbcType=DATE})
    </insert>  
...
```

Here's the model:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Integer fooId;
    private final Integer gcorId;
    private final Date registrationDate;

    public Foo(final Integer fooId, final Integer gcorId, final Date registrationDate)     {
        this.fooId = fooId;
        this.gcorId = gcorId;
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }
...
```

And here's the call:

```
... 
Foo foo = new Foo(null, 229, null);
fooMapper.insertFooObject(foo);
...
```

fooMapper is injected by spring and can be used successfully for other SQL statements.  When I pass in a number for fooId and registrationDate is null, everything works.  When fooId is null (as shown), I get the error:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
 Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
 The error may involve defaultParameterMap
 The error occurred while setting parameters
 SQL: insert into foos (foo_id, gcor_id, registration_date)         values (?, ?, ?)
 Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource">
        <property name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>        
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@......"/>
        <property name="username" value="..."/>
        <property name="password" value="..."/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fooMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
        <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.foo.FooMapper" />
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Any ideas how to correct this?  I didn't have luck googling and thought I'd be okay by specifying jdbcType. Thanks!

Comment: can we see your mybatis configuration file?

Comment: sure, added config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem in the model class (Foo.java):

```
public int getFooId() {
    return fooId;
}
```

fooId is an Integer and not an int.  By changing the getter return type to an Integer, I was able to insert a null primary key and get the trigger-created sequence id back

Comment: This is exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `useGeneratedkeys` for oracle, which oracle does not supprot. GeneratedKeys are supported by mysql and postgress I believe. Instead use selectkeys to fetch the next value or as you are ok to pass the null value to fooId remove the `useGeneratedKeys`  which is by default is `false`. You can get next value using sequence

```
<selectKey keyProperty="fooId"
             resultClass="int">
    SELECT nextVal('foo_id_seq')
 </selectKey>
```

Comment: This post suggests that it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234718/how-to-obtain-last-insert-id-in-oracle-using-mybatis

Comment: Also, even when I remove that part so I just have <insert id="insertFooObject"> ..., I get the same error

Comment: I should add that when I pass in individual fields instead of an object, I don't get the error: <insert id="insertFoo">
        insert into foos (foo_id, gcor_id, registration_date)
        values (#{fooId, jdbcType=NUMERIC}, #{gcorId}, #{registrationDate, jdbcType=DATE})
    </insert>

Comment: If you read the link , he is inserting value using trigger and he just wants the inserted back. I believe why you getting the error was you have fooId has primary key and on error mybatis tries map to an error during which its unable to find error mapping object or something of that kind and throws null pointer error

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this.  By changing the getter return type, I was able to insert a null primary key and get the trigger-created sequence id back.