# How to get generated key in oracle 12c with mybatis

Tags: auto-increment, mybatis, oracle12c

I used identity column in oracle 12c:

```
col1 NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

I use Spring + mybatis, how to get generated value, useGeneratedKeys seems doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: provide more code snippet  so that we can tell you what is (not) going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, the [question has been asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252611/7076047).

You might not notice the generated value is not returned by the insert statement, but stored in the input parameter in the *keyProperty*.

Comment: Finally I use, thanks for your information:

    BEGIN
    insert into tbl(..) values(...)
    returning cId into #{cId, mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER};
    END;