# Return primary key on insert does not work myBatis-Spring

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have the following table and sequence

```
CREATE TABLE teacher
(
  teacher_id serial NOT NULL,
  teacher_name character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT teacher_pkey PRIMARY KEY (teacher_id)
)


CREATE SEQUENCE teacher_teacher_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

and want to get the primary key whenever I insert new record. When I run the following query, it works and return the primary key I want.

```
INSERT INTO teacher( teacher_name ) VALUES ('John') RETURNING teacher_id;
```

But when I use myBatis-Spring Mapper as follows

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO teacher( teacher_name ) " +
        "VALUES ( #{teacherName} ) RETURNING teacher_id" )
public int insertTeacher(Teacher teacher);
```

and call the function with valid `teacher` object, it inserted the value but returns -1.

And I also tried the followings

```
@Insert("INSERT INTO teacher( teacher_id, teacher_name ) " +
            "VALUES ( #{teacherId}, #{teacherName} )" )
@SelectKey(statement="SELECT nextval('teacher_teacher_id_seq');", keyProperty="teacherId", before=true, resultType=int.class)
public int insertTeacher(Teacher teacher);
```

this return 1 no matter how many times I call

Can anyone tell me the reason why and give me the solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show code inside `insertTeacher`

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ There is no code inside insertTeacher, I am using myBatis-Spring framework where we just need to declare function along with the sql as above in the interface (Mapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of search, unlike the solution given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283159/how-to-return-ids-on-inserts-with-mybatis-in-mysql-with-annotations) which might work for older versions or iBatis(but this does not work with latest version), I found out that myBatis 3.x.x simply does not support returning auto generate id/key on insert. Instead it returns the number row updated, so in my case it returns 1. You can read more on this [link](http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/insert-always-returns-quot-1-quot-instead-of-the-newly-generated-key-value-td1644219.html).